# Shared View Model between two fragments in the nav_graph

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation

I have an app with one activity and about 29 Fragment in the `nav_graph`, two of these fragments are used for authentication, and I need to share data between these two fragments using a `shared view model` but not with the other fragments.

So, I created my `ViewModel` and instantiated it in both fragments using the `viewModels()` which is a part of `fragment-ktx` library.

```kotlin
private val viewModel: AuthViewModel by viewModels()
```

However, once I navigate to the second fragment using the `findNavController().navigate()` I lose all the data in the `AuthViewModel`

**AuthViewModel.kt**

```kotlin
class AuthViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository
) : BaseViewModel()
```

Is there any additional step I'm missing here?

**EDIT**

I'm accessing the data from the `onViewCreated` method

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create a viewmodel by `viewmodels()` yout get a reference to the ViewModel scoped to the current Fragment.

So in your case you would be using `private val viewModel: AuthViewModel by viewModels()` in both the fragment which gives you two different instance of viewmodel tied to each fragment.

The concept of Shared Viewmodel need a Shared Scope like `Activity` or `NavGraph`.

1. Using Activity

Just change

```
private val viewModel: AuthViewModel by viewModels()
```

to

```
private val viewModel: AuthViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

2. Using NavGraph

Create another nav graph where you have two fragments which are used for authentication.

```
<navigation android:id="@+id/authenticationNavGraph" 
        app:startDestination="@id/chooseRecipient">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/authentication1Fragment"
            android:name="com.example.AuthFragment1"
            android:label="Fragment 1">
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/authentication2Fragment"
            android:name="com.example.AuthFragment2"
            android:label="Fragment 2" />
</navigation>
```

Now If you want to use same viewmodel `AuthViewModel` then you can create a viewmodel using:

```
private val viewModel: AuthViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.authenticationNavGraph)
```